# ImageView rotate 360 with animation

Tags: java, android

I want to rotate the ImageView with animation (duration), let's assume that I set the rotation to 350 degrees, then I want to animate the rotation to 80 degrees (shorter way), unfortunately the image is animated from right to left (anti clockwise), which is the longer way.

```
image.animate().rotation(350).setDuration(500).start();
... time interval ...
image.animate().rotation(80).setDuration(500).start();
```

Comment: I am not sure but can you try angle = 80 + 360 = 440, image.animate().rotation(440).setDuration(500).start();

Comment: I'm afraid that this will only work in one case when I know the numbers, unfortunately I don't know what numbers/degrees will be next, I always want one to make the shortest possible distance from the other...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd be better served using the `rotationBy` method of the `ViewPropertyAnimator` and the problem then becomes computing a **signed delta** between "start" and "end" values, applying the "shortest" criteria (clockwise/anti-clockwise).  This does require having both the previous and current values to compute delta.

The following is a simple demo of applying a `rotationBy` always rotating using the "shortest" (clockwise or anticlockwise) based on the computed delta.

The test generates a list of headings and then adds random heading ( [0,360) ) values.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Integer[] t1 = { 350, 12, 340, 20, 330, 30, 320, 40, 310, 50, 300, 60, 290, 70, 285, 75, 280, 80, 275, 85, 270, 90};
    Integer[] t2 = { 265, 95, 260, 100, 255, 105, 250, 110, 245, 115, 240, 120, 235, 125, 230, 130, 225, 135, 220, 140, 215, 145, 210, 150};
    Integer[] t3 = { 0, 0, 340, 320, 300, 280, 260, 240, 220, 200, 180, 160, 140, 120, 100, 80, 60, 40, 20, 0};

    ImageView iv;
    Random r;
    TextView from; TextView to; TextView deltaTv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        iv = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        List<Integer> hdgs = new ArrayList<>();
        r = new Random();

        hdgs.addAll(Arrays.asList(t1));
        hdgs.addAll(Arrays.asList(t2));
        hdgs.addAll(Arrays.asList(t3));

        // add in some random
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            hdgs.add(r.nextInt(360));
        }

        from = findViewById(R.id.textViewFrom);
        to = findViewById(R.id.textViewTo);
        deltaTv = findViewById(R.id.delta);

        // start at 0
        to.setText("0");

        // Updated positions every 1 second
        Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // newHdg initially ranges from [0,360)
                int newHdg = hdgs.remove(0);
                // prevHdg is saved value (from textview in this demo)
                int prevHdg = Integer.parseInt(to.getText().toString());

                // move old "to" to new "from"
                from.setText(to.getText());

                // Compute "delta" and enforcing clockwise/anticlockwise by using
                // sign of value - likely can be reduced...
                int delta = computeDelta(prevHdg, newHdg);

                deltaTv.setText(Integer.toString(delta));
                to.setText(Integer.toString(newHdg));

                Log.i("", "Animating ...p="+prevHdg+" c="+newHdg+" d="+delta);

                iv.animate().rotationBy(delta).setDuration(500).start();

                if (hdgs.size() > 0) {
                    h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                } else {
                    Log.i("","Done");
                }

            }
        }, 2000);

    }

    // Compute delta between "to" and "from" and enforcing clockwise/anti-clockwise to
    // achieve "shortest" rotation.  Likely could be reduced...
    private int computeDelta(int from, int to) {
        int result = 0;
        if (from > to) {
            result = (from - to);
            if (result <= 180) {
                result *= -1;
            } else {
                result = (360 + to - from);
            }
        } else {
            result = (to - from);
            if (result > 180) {
                result = -1 * (360 + from - to);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

[image]

The textviews contain "start" heading, "end" heading and computed delta.